# NSTableRowView backgroundColor only draws around subviews

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

In a sidebar style outline view, when I set the `backgroundColor` to white on the row view passed in to `outlineView:didAddRowView:row:`, it only draws around the row's contents. Under the subviews, the regular background still shows. How do I just get the whole row to draw white?

[image: row screenshot]

Comment: Try to play with making view layer backed to the view having your tree. Or some of the views in the stack of views. Maybe even entire window. I've seen that before. The problem is that sidebar style uses effect view which is layer backed. So there is some collision in rendering.

Answer (score 1):

As `Eugene Mankovski` pointed, you have to make the view layer backed. This snippet will help you.

```
extension NSView {

     var customBackgroundColor: NSColor? {
        get {
            if let colorRef = self.layer?.backgroundColor {
                return NSColor(CGColor: colorRef)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            self.wantsLayer = true
            self.layer?.backgroundColor = newValue?.CGColor
        }
    }
}
```

And access it like this in your view.

```
self.yourView.customBackgroundColor = NSColor.lightGrayColor()
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me - the background color doesn't get drawn.

Comment: @Uncommon You are applying this to which view? NSOutlineView?

Comment: Yes, it's a sidebar style NSOutlineView.

Comment: @Uncommon Can Draw Concurrently = true ?